# Transaction shows transferred instead of sent and zero bitcoins sent to zero recipient

Tags: blockchain.info

[image]

[image]

I sent 0.00185 BTC to this bitcoin address 14UdCugXpW3ukYgGPNM18v3VqVxyp3S3Ak using blockchain.info wallet,
But transaction log shows 0.0 BTC transferred to zero recipient with transaction fee boldly written.

The transaction has been confirmed in blockchain but the recipient address is not showing on the transaction log and blockchain.

Don't know if the recipient have seen the bitcoin.
Please help.

TX ID :
https://blockchain.info/tx/6e4c6f24326f922201f90874663d609bf787639f13c8ca9378dd09183b09dc11

Comment: @pebwindkraft: Not a duplicate of that. Asker states that "The transaction has been confirmed in the blockchain." and it actually has 25 confirmations.

Comment: Sam: Where were you looking at the transaction log and that the "recipient address is not showing on the transaction log and blockchain"? The transaction you're linking only sends to one address and it is not the mentioned. If you had pasted the address mentioned here as a recipient, I'd say you have found a bug in blockchain.info.—— Also, why did you tag this with "Bitcoin Core"? Was the recipient address from a Bitcoin Core wallet?

Comment: @murch: you are right, I have deleted my comment - I just checked on blockexplorer.com and blockchain.info, both show from/to address being the same. This tx has nothing sent to 14UdCugX... all funds are still in your original wallet, minus the tx fees.

Comment: I really appreciate your concern. Please see the image above. The coin transferred was deducted from my wallet and it wasn't displayed on the transaction log, even the recipient address disappeared. Recipient didn't receive the funds.Its likely to be a bug on blockchain.info.

Answer (score 1):

The TX id you posted is wrong. The correct one is https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/a6334b9b391d98083b3f011d6fcf5e097f5c67dbe10ecf41442d335a4694ae2f/

It is showing that 0.00185 BTC was indeed sent to: 14UdCugXpW3ukYgGPNM18v3VqVxyp3S3Ak

After that a large TX was sent that contains 58 inputs one of which is 14UdCugXpW3ukYgGPNM18v3VqVxyp3S3Ak

TX: https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/792405e7a85a468d0cbfa99ac7fc7c4409942768a91d26eb13e8fb9efba46c95/

If the recipient and the owner of 14UdCugXpW3ukYgGPNM18v3VqVxyp3S3Ak did not sent that TX, the priv key of 14UdCugXpW3ukYgGPNM18v3VqVxyp3S3Ak is most likely got compromised and the funds were stolen. Sorry.